# How to make data randomization faster in R?

Tags: r

I have very big data set and I'm computing thousands of models for it. For every model I need to randomize my data 100 times.This randomization part makes my script very slow.
Would someone help me to make this step faster?

Here is my code:

```
    for (l in seq(repeat.times)) {


    y <- as.matrix(dfr[1])
    x <- as.matrix(dfr[2:ncol(dfr)])
        # Random Generation

                x.random.name = sample(colnames(x),1,replace=FALSE)
                x.random.1 <- sample(x[,x.random.name],nrow(y),replace=FALSE)
                x <- cbind(x,x.random.1)

.
.
.
```

For example:

```
> x
     A B  C  D  E
[1,] 1 5  9 13 17
[2,] 2 6 10 14 18
[3,] 3 7 11 15 19
[4,] 4 8 12 16 20

> y
     [,1]
[1,]   10
[2,]   20
[3,]   30
[4,]   40
```

After randomization:

```
> x
     A B  C  D  E x.random.1
[1,] 1 5  9 13 17         10
[2,] 2 6 10 14 18         12
[3,] 3 7 11 15 19          9
[4,] 4 8 12 16 20         11
>
```

Comment: Are you really sampling the columns, or should that be rows?

Comment: in the setting of my problem, I'm sampling the column.

Comment: I would sample the column **numbers**, not the names.

Comment: Is that code called in a loop, 100 times?

Comment: What is `y`? Can you provide a bit more info about the data, or perhaps the data?

Comment: It seems to me you're just randomly selecting a column, then permuting it and binding it to the right of `x`. Object `y` isn't necessary given your example. Would this suffice: `for (i in seq_len(repeat.times)) x[[ncol(x) + 1]] <- sample(x[, sample(ncol(x), 1)])`?

Comment: it will make it faster ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? (PS: it assumes `x` is a `data.frame`)

Comment: Cuz it takes an hour to run

Comment: Almost sure that `x <- cbind(x,x.random.1)` is root of your problem..

Comment: What are the dimensions of `dfr`, and what is your `repeat.times`? You say it takes an hour to run, but you could benchmark it with fewer reps to get a rough indication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you could dramatically reduce the runtime by moving x and y outside the loop. Then you can just create a new transformed matrix in the loop

```
y <- as.matrix(dfr[1])
XX <- as.matrix(dfr[2:ncol(dfr)])

for (l in seq(repeat.times)) {
    # Random Generation
    x.random.name = sample(colnames(x),1,replace=FALSE)
    x.random.1 <- sample(XX[,x.random.name],nrow(y),replace=FALSE)
    x <- cbind(XX,x.random.1)
}
```

So i've moved out `x` and renamed it. Then when you do your analysis, you would continue to use the newly made x. I found that with [my benchmark](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=qeKBTVPk) this speed things up by nearly two orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

This is way way faster if I understand OP's requirement correctly

```
x
##      A B  C  D  E
## [1,] 1 5  9 13 17
## [2,] 2 6 10 14 18
## [3,] 3 7 11 15 19
## [4,] 4 8 12 16 20

y
##      [,1]
## [1,]   10
## [2,]   20
## [3,]   30
## [4,]   40

xncol <- ncol(x)
ynrow <- nrow(y)

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(xrand <- sapply(1:100, FUN = function(iter) {
    sample(x[, sample(1:xncol, 1)], ynrow)
}), times = 1L)
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                                                                         expr      min
##  xrand <- sapply(1:100, FUN = function(iter) {     sample(x[, sample(1:xncol, 1)], ynrow) }) 1.083906
##        lq   median       uq      max neval
##  1.083906 1.083906 1.083906 1.083906     1



x <- cbind(x, xrand)

x
##      A B  C  D  E                                                                                           
## [1,] 1 5  9 13 17 8 16 2 18 5 3 10 10 14  9 19 6 6 15 18 2 13 13 15 18 7 20 17 11 13 1 16 1 20 1  9 19 14 20
## [2,] 2 6 10 14 18 7 14 3 20 8 4 12  9 13 10 20 8 8 13 20 1 14 15 16 20 6 19 19 10 16 2 15 4 17 4 12 20 15 19
## [3,] 3 7 11 15 19 5 15 1 19 7 2 11 12 15 11 18 7 7 14 17 4 15 16 14 19 8 17 18  9 14 4 14 2 18 3 11 18 16 17
## [4,] 4 8 12 16 20 6 13 4 17 6 1  9 11 16 12 17 5 5 16 19 3 16 14 13 17 5 18 20 12 15 3 13 3 19 2 10 17 13 18
##                                                                                                             
## [1,] 5 13 2 3 5 2 5 8 4 6 19 3 7 19 4 7 6 4 17  9 18  9 5 3 1 15 8 19 19 3 19 15 15 1 1 10 15 19 11 6 5 17 7
## [2,] 7 15 1 1 7 1 6 6 3 8 18 2 6 17 2 6 5 3 18 10 17 11 8 1 3 13 6 17 18 4 17 16 13 4 3 11 16 18  9 8 8 18 6
## [3,] 8 14 3 2 8 3 8 7 2 7 20 1 8 18 3 8 8 1 20 12 19 10 6 2 2 16 5 20 17 2 18 13 16 3 4 12 13 20 12 7 7 20 8
## [4,] 6 16 4 4 6 4 7 5 1 5 17 4 5 20 1 5 7 2 19 11 20 12 7 4 4 14 7 18 20 1 20 14 14 2 2  9 14 17 10 5 6 19 5
##                                                                  
## [1,] 3 3 15 19 2 12 16 11 18 7 10 11 5 12 12 10 1 2 19 2 16 17 11
## [2,] 4 2 13 20 1 11 15 12 17 5 11 12 6 10  9 11 4 3 18 3 14 19  9
## [3,] 1 4 16 18 4 10 14  9 19 8 12  9 8 11 11  9 3 4 20 4 13 20 12
## [4,] 2 1 14 17 3  9 13 10 20 6  9 10 7  9 10 12 2 1 17 1 15 18 10
```

The key step is ofcourse, which I have wrapped in microbenchmark purely for benchmarking purpose.

```
xrand <- sapply(1:100, FUN = function(iter) {     sample(x[, sample(1:xncol, 1)], ynrow) })
```

Comment: Good answer. I think `replicate` is more appropriate than `sapply` in this situation. I did like your double use of `sample`, however.

Comment: @nograpes : `replicate` is a wrapper for `sapply`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner:

```
# Data
x<-matrix(1:10^4,nrow=10)
# Generate 2000 replicates.
replicate(2000,x[order(runif(nrow(x))),sample(ncol(x),1)])
```

Or even just:

```
replicate(2000,sample(x[,sample(ncol(x),1)]))
```